# Count grouped members of JSON array with jq 1.3 with inline output

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I have a JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "instance_AZs": [
        "us-east-1b",
        "us-east-1b",
        "us-east-1b",
        "us-east-1c",
        "us-east-1c",
        "us-east-1a",
        "us-east-1a",
        "us-east-1c",
        "us-east-1b",
        "us-east-1a",
        "us-east-1a",
        "us-east-1c",
        "us-east-1a",
        "us-east-1b",
        "us-east-1b",
        "us-east-1c",
        "us-east-1c",
        "us-east-1b"
    ],
    "ASGname": "myapp"
  }
]
```

Desired output is:

```
myapp.us-east-1a.5
myapp.us-east-1b.7
myapp.us-east-1c.6
```

As far as I can go with jq 1.3 syntax, I wrote this code:

```
cat file.json | jq -r '.[] | .ASGname, (.instance_AZs | group_by(.) | map(. | length , (. | unique ) [] ))'
```

Which produce an output:

```
myapp
[
  5,
  "us-east-1a",
  7,
  "us-east-1b",
  6,
  "us-east-1c"
]
```

Can you please advice how to generate desired output?

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do it:

```
jq -r '.[]|.ASGname as $g|.instance_AZs|group_by(.)[]|"\($g).\(.[0]).\(length)"' file.json
```

Comment: This one is amazing and work with jq 1.5. Thank you! Is there is any way to avoid join? To make it work with 1.3?

Comment: I have no `jq-1.3` for testing. Does string interpolation work with 1.3? Does this work with 1.3: `jq '"\(.foo)"' <<< '{"foo":"bar"}'` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl yes it does

Comment: @hek2mgl you don't need `tostring` in string interpolation. *Whatever the expression returns will be interpolated into the string.*

Comment: @oguzismail true! removed (it was a leftover from the previous version with `join`)

Comment: @hek2mgl, thank you! That was exactly what I need and your syntax is clearly readable.

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)

Answer (score 2):

```sh
.[]
| .ASGname as $p
| reduce .instance_AZs[] as $k ({}; .[$k]+=1)
| keys_unsorted[] as $k
| "\($p).\($k).\(.[$k])"
```

reduce `instance_AZs` to an object where unique array elements are keys to their repetition counts in the array, use it for producing desired output.

or, if you insist on doing this your way, pipe groups to an interpolated string instead of `map`, i.e refer to @hek2mgl's answer.